# Input/output error when accessing a directory

Tags: filesystem, disk-management

I have ubuntu 14.04 installed on a 256Gb SSD (Sandisk). The drive is partitioned to 120 GB (with OS) and the rest as a secondary Data partition. The Data partition has started having I/O problems this morning.
Both partitions are Ext4 (version 1).
I have run badblocks and it found 20.
Is is worth formatting the dodgy partition?

Screenshots:
[image: Badblocks output]

Comment: I have run *smart --all /dev/sdb* which reports test result:PASSED.

Comment: dmesg shows many errors such as "unable to read itable block" - it recommends running e2fsck

Comment: e2fsck said "UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY"

Answer (score 1):

Work out the exact drive name if you are not sure from Disks.
In my example the assessment says

> one bad sector

1. Under volumes the device name is /dev/sdb2
2. The file system is ext4
3. The drive must be unmounted

Run> fsck.ext4 -f -C0 /dev/sdb2
(if you don't want to be prompted all the time add the -y option)

[image: Disks output screenshot]

Note: After running this command I can use the drive although I seem to have lost a few files.